# Use of thawed Beef blood

Tags: food-safety, gravy

I recently thawed a roast and put blood aside to use to add to gravy mix. Was this dangerous to do? It was brought to a boil.

Answer (score 1):

You should be ok as long as it is properly cooked (boiled)

People will often (re)use juices from raw meat in sauces.

For example, you can use the leftover marinade as a base for a sauce.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that (as far as I know) the liquid was almost certainly not blood; proper slaughter/butchery removes all the blood from meat and the pinkish liquid is a mixture of water and proteins.

Comment: @dbmag9 that's not entirely correct. Only perfusion would be capable of removing all blood. Proper slaughter removes almost all the blood in larger blood vessels, but is entirely incapable of removing it from things like capillaries. Storage of blood results in hemolysis, which releases hemoglobin to form the pink/red colour... it's still blood, just a different form.

Comment: @dbmag9 meat does not have blood, veins and arteries have blood.

Answer (score -3):

It is a popular misconception that meat contains blood. Mammals have blood in there veins and in there arteries not in there meat. What meat does contain is hemoglobin which is off course also present in blood. It is a case of all thumbs are fingers but not all fingers are thumbs.

When an animal is slaughtered it is customary to have the carcass hang for a certain period to let all the blood drain out. Any full carcass that you as consumer will interact with will definitely not have any blood.

Actual real blood is quite dangerous. There is a reason why no butcher in the West sells the blood of animals. The risk of dangerous pathogens being spread like this is just simply to great.

That is why I do believe what is sold as blood sausage is really a fraud. You are only going to get real blood sausage made on the day of the pigs slaughtering. You can only use blood if you slaughter animals yourself and even then it has to be used immediately.

The defrost juices are probably just dampness from the melting of the ice crystals mixed with the hemoglobin present in the muscles of the meat.

Comment: Do you have any sources for "actual real blood is quite dangerous"? FWIW, my local butcher sells pigs blood.

Comment: That is incorrect. Fresh (and dried) blood is available for sale and perfectly legal in Europe. And claiming that  blood sausage is a fraud would offend not only the [Confrérie des Chevaliers du Goûte Boudin](http://www.boudin-mortagne.com/Page_ang.html) but also a lot of traditional regional dishes like the British black pudding, German and Austrian Blutwurst, French boudin noir etc.

Comment: Incidentally, "meat" does contain blood (hanging the carcass empties the major blood vessels but not the capillaries), but the red exudate from the muscle fibers themselves is myoglobin, not hemoglobin.